# Проблема с выводом с json файла

Tags: python, json

Структура json файла такова

[image: структура]

Кодом сохраняю все classid из ветки "descriptions" и проверяю их по ветке "assets" и копирую оттуда amount сохраняя в новый словарь. Если при нахождении classid в дереве "assets" этот classid существует в словари, то переменная amount складывается, если classid нет в словаре, то добавляется в словарь classid и amount. Проблема состоит в том, что в итоге у меня получается, что числа неправильные, то есть количество предмета в инвентаре - 17, а он мне выдает 34. При попытке делить на два теряю большую часть данных. Что с этим делать не знаю.
Что получаю в консоли по итогу
[image: [IMG]]
Примерно такую картину, переводя в int объект счисления amount = int(asset['amount']) получаю конечно приятный ответ, в том виде, в котором мне нужен, но все же неправильный
[image: [IMG]]
classid 4418618853 соответствует кейсу Snakebite Case, которых в моем инвентаре 17[image: [IMG]]
причем по поиску в самом json файле находит то 18 объектов этого classid, то 19 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Как все это нормализовать? По итогу мне нужно чтобы код правильно считал количество classid в дереве assets

```
import json

with open('checker.json', 'r') as j:
    data = json.loads(j.read())

def main():
    total_amount = {}
    for item in data['descriptions']:
        market_hash_name = item['market_hash_name']
        classid = item['classid']
        for asset in data['assets']:
            if asset['classid'] == classid:
                amount = asset['amount']
                if classid in total_amount:
                    total_amount[classid] += amount
                else:
                    total_amount[classid] = amount
        

for classid, amount in total_amount.items():
    print(f'classid: {classid}, amount: {amount}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Так-же структура дерева assets [image: структура assets]

и структура дерева descriptions [image: структура descriptions]

(если необходимо)

Comment: то, что находит больше объектов больше как ненужная просто информация, потому что если смотреть по дереву assets все сходится, остальные совпадения по дереву descriptions

Comment: Вы уверены что в `descriptions` нет дубликата 4418618853? Если не уверены, то лучше сделать проверку на дубликаты.

Comment: вообще иногда бывают да, каким образом их можно исключить кодом?

Comment: В цикле `for item in data['descriptions']:` проверять есть ли в `total_amount` ключ с таким же `classid` если да то пропускать.